# Ubuntu/Windows Boot Manager Issue

Tags: 18.04, windows

Okay....Ubuntu 18.4/Windows 10 (latest)

Today I decided to use my extra HDD to run Ubuntu. I have a 1TB 970 EVO NVMe for Windows 10 and a spare 1TB HDD.

I format the spare 1TB HDD

I used an already setup thumb drive using rufus to load up Ubuntu.

I choose the install along side Windows, but I choose the HDD and in no way partitioned space on my NVMe for Ubuntu.

Everything loads up fine, updates, restarts, etc.

Then I got to get back into Windows and on the grub menu it shows that I have **TWO** Windows Boot Manager options. One on my NVMe drive and the other on the HDD, and selecting either Windows Boot option throws me in a recovery/diagnostic mode where it tells me it can do neither.

In order to get back into Windows I have to change the boot order in BIOS of the NVMe Windows over Ubuntu or Override boot up, but then I don't get to choose Ubuntu.

Why can I override boot my Windows Boot Manager on the NVMe in BIOS and Windows 10 loads fine, but the same done in grub throws and Windows 10 throws a fit. Do I need the Windows Boot Manager on the HDD? How do I get rid of the Boot Manager on the HDD and put the Ubuntu one there instead?

Comment: Try installing rEFInd on whatever OS and see if it can detect all your bootloaders. Make sure your HDD is plugged in while you install it.

Comment: I will be working on it this weekend. I have never used anything like rEFInd before and it isn't exactly a click-and-drag thing.

Answer (score 0):

Also maybe try update-grub and then grub install onto the main HDD. The Ubuntu installer might have found the recovery partition only. sudo update-grub and sudo grub-install. Report back if it helped.

Comment: I will be working on it this weekend. I have never used anything like rEFInd before and it isn't exactly a click-and-drag thing.

Comment: I found the boot loaders without rEFInd. I did update-grub. I disabled all but Ubuntu and windows 10 boot on the NVMe. I disabled fast boot and Hyberbootenabled=0 in registry. When trying to launch windows from grub2 it still triggers Windows Automatic Repair. Thoughts?